# Pattern matching removing wiki markup tags

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to grab a user's email address from a field in Jira that's using wiki markup. The field content is as follows:

`*User Email:* [useraddress@gmail.com|mailto:useraddress@gmail.com]
*Tech Email:* [techaddress@gmail.com|mailto:techaddress@gmail.com]`

I need to create a regex that will match either the email of the 'User' or the 'Tech' email, not  both at the same time. I'm unable to create a regex that will match that specifically. I'm using a tool that the underlying implementation is based on Java's Pattern class and uses Matcher.find() to find matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this expression to match only user emails:

```
(?:User\sEmail:\*\s\[)([\w\-@.]+)
```

Here you can see how it works: https://regexr.com/51f8s

Java example:

```java
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(
        "*User Email:* [useraddress@gmail.com|mailto:useraddress@gmail.com]",
        "*Tech Email:* [techaddress@gmail.com|mailto:techaddress@gmail.com]"
);

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:User\\sEmail:\\*\\s\\[)([\\w\\-@.]+)");
for (String item : items) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(item);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("email: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
email: useraddress@gmail.com
```

Comment: That's it! It worked as expected! Thank you!!